# How to add fields to Firebase Auth?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am totally new to Firebase (typically use sql), but I need to do a few things ---

1. I have a register page with 2 fields `name, password`, and it is just using that auth feature in firebase

I need to add company name to that, as well as a couple of other custom fields. How do I do this?

Take a look at this picture to see the way it is set up in the auth feature in firebase:

[image: how would I add those fields in there for when I create the user, and then also use them pragmatically?]

How would I add those fields in there for when I create the user, and then also use them programatically?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Firebase Auth do not support that yet as adding custom fields to The Console .. But I also solved this issue by using Database (Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database) as I can add custom fileds linked to the user using his UID as I create Collection 'users' when user signup I create document to the user with his UID then store this fileds (e.g fileds you mentioned) .. So this is the best way to do that as Firebase Auth do not support that yet

Wish I helped you :)